# Access database "Corrupt" in 2007; opens in 2010

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, corruption

I have an accdb database that is used by multiple individuals and stored on a network share. When opened in Acccess 2007 the following message appears:

> Cannot open database "*\\databasepath\filename.accdb*". It may not be a database that your application recognizes or the file may be corrupt

Access 2010 opens the database with no problems.

What is the most common cause of this issue? I searched for database repair tools and can't find any Microsoft tools for accdb files (JetCompact didn't do it). I ran a compact and repair via Access 2010, did a save as locally and then copied it over to the share - no effect.

Other than magically upgrading all my users to Access 2010 (which won't happen) I'm in the dark here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have some features you're using in 2010 that aren't supported in 2007.

[Look here for more info.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/dn602608(v=office.14))

Comment: Excellent! I'll go give these a try

Comment: Turned out that one of the reports prevented the database from opening in 2007. I was never able to isolate the exact cause, but I solved it by re-importing each different type of object one group at a time (I.E. first imported tables, then imported queries, then imported reports...). When I discovered that the reports caused it, I spooled off multiple copies of the database and tried importing a different subset of reports each time. We finally winnowed down the problem report and then recreated that report in the freshly re-imported database.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely someone opened it in 2010, edited your report and saved the change. This will break 2007 every time. 2010 is NOT backwards compatible with 2007

Comment: Definitely was the cause of the issue. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

I would make a back-up, make another back-up and then first try importing all but the tables that contain attachments into a new database.

you can also check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/ms-access-mdb-ldb-database-corrupted